# Modify an itab during looping another itab

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I want to do the following

```
Loop at itab into wa_itab.
   wa_itab2-field1 = wa_itab-field1.
   wa_itab2-field2 = wa_itab-field2.
   wa_itab2-field3 = wa_itab-field3.
   wa_itab2-field4 = wa_itab-field4.
*how to insert in itab2 if fields 1,2 & 3 do not exist or update itab2 if fields 1,2 & 3 exist?
EndLoop.
```

Let me explain more.
I have itab with fields bukrs, kunnr, date, action.
The itab2 with fields bukrs, kunnr, name1 (from kna1),date01 (jan), action01, date02 (Feb), action02 ... date12 (Dec), action12.
During loop of itab I want if the itab2 has a record with bukrs and kunnr then it will update date and action according to the month of itab-date, if it do not exist (bukrs, kunnr) then insert a record to itab2.

I hope that this explains what I want.

Thanks in advance
Elias

PS. Here is the program

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  Z_COLLECTORS_ACTIONS
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Description
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Change log:
*& Date          Author        Action
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  z_collectors_actions.

TABLES: zcollectoraction, kna1, t001.

TYPE-POOLS : slis.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_totalcollectoractions,
         bukrs  TYPE zcollectoraction-bukrs,
         kunnr  TYPE zcollectoraction-kunnr,
         name1  TYPE kna1-name1,
         date01 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date02 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date03 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date04 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date05 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date06 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date07 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date08 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date09 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date10 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date11 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         date12 TYPE zcollectoraction-dat,
         action01 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action02 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action03 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action04 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action05 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action06 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action07 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action08 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action09 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action10 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action11 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
         action12 TYPE zcollectoraction-action,
       END OF ty_totalcollectoractions.

DATA: wa_collectoraction LIKE zcollectoraction,
      it_collectoraction LIKE TABLE OF zcollectoraction,
      wa_totalcollectoractions TYPE ty_totalcollectoractions,
      it_totalcollectoractions TYPE TABLE OF ty_totalcollectoractions WITH KEY kunnr.

DATA: fieldcatalog TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv WITH HEADER LINE,
      field_catalog TYPE lvc_t_fcat,
      gd_layout    TYPE slis_layout_alv,
      gd_repid     LIKE sy-repid,
      g_save TYPE c VALUE 'X',
      g_variant TYPE disvariant,
      gx_variant TYPE disvariant,
      g_exit TYPE c.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK bl1 WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
PARAMETERS: variant LIKE disvariant-variant.
PARAMETERS p_bukrs TYPE bukrs OBLIGATORY.
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_kunnr FOR kna1-kunnr OBLIGATORY,
                so_date  FOR sy-datum OBLIGATORY.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK bl1.

INITIALIZATION.
  gx_variant-report = sy-repid.
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_VARIANT_DEFAULT_GET'
    EXPORTING
      i_save     = g_save
    CHANGING
      cs_variant = gx_variant
    EXCEPTIONS
      not_found  = 2.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    variant = gx_variant-variant.
  ENDIF.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  SELECT bukrs kunnr dat MAX( time ) AS time
    FROM zcollectoraction INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_collectoraction
    WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs AND
          kunnr IN so_kunnr AND
          dat   IN so_date
    GROUP BY bukrs kunnr dat.

  LOOP AT it_collectoraction INTO wa_collectoraction.
    SELECT SINGLE * FROM zcollectoraction INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF wa_collectoraction
      WHERE bukrs = wa_collectoraction-bukrs AND
            kunnr = wa_collectoraction-kunnr AND
            dat   = wa_collectoraction-dat   AND
            time  = wa_collectoraction-time.

    MODIFY it_collectoraction FROM wa_collectoraction.

    wa_totalcollectoractions-bukrs = wa_collectoraction-bukrs.
    wa_totalcollectoractions-kunnr = wa_collectoraction-kunnr.

    SELECT SINGLE name1 FROM kna1 INTO wa_totalcollectoractions-name1
      WHERE kunnr = wa_collectoraction-kunnr.

    DATA lv_month TYPE n LENGTH 2.

    lv_month = wa_collectoraction-dat+4(2).

    CASE lv_month.
      WHEN '01'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date01 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action01 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '02'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date02 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action02 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '03'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date03 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action03 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '04'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date04 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action04 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '05'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date05 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action05 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '06'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date06 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action06 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '07'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date07 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action07 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '08'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date08 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action08 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '09'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date09 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action09 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '10'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date10 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action10 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '11'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date11 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action11 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN '12'.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-date12 = wa_collectoraction-dat.
        wa_totalcollectoractions-action12 = wa_collectoraction-action.
      WHEN OTHERS.
    ENDCASE.

    READ TABLE it_totalcollectoractions INTO wa_totalcollectoractions
                        WITH TABLE KEY kunnr = wa_collectoraction-kunnr.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
      MODIFY it_totalcollectoractions INDEX sy-tabix FROM wa_totalcollectoractions.
    ELSE.
      INSERT wa_totalcollectoractions INTO TABLE it_totalcollectoractions.
    ENDIF.

  ENDLOOP.

  PERFORM build_fieldcatalog_agreggate.
  PERFORM display_alv_report.


*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  DISPLAY_ALV_REPORT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*  -->  p1        text
*  <--  p2        text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM display_alv_report .
  gd_repid = sy-repid.
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      i_callback_program      = gd_repid
      i_callback_top_of_page  = 'TOP-OF-PAGE'  "see FORM
      i_callback_user_command = 'USER_COMMAND'
      it_fieldcat             = fieldcatalog[]
      i_save                  = 'X'
      is_variant              = g_variant
    TABLES
      t_outtab                = it_totalcollectoractions
    EXCEPTIONS
      program_error           = 1
      OTHERS                  = 2.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO
*         WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.
  ENDIF.

ENDFORM.                    " DISPLAY_ALV_REPORT

*-------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Form  TOP-OF-PAGE                                                 *
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*
* ALV Report Header                                                 *
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM top-of-page.
*ALV Header declarations
  DATA: t_header TYPE slis_t_listheader,
        wa_header TYPE slis_listheader,
        t_line LIKE wa_header-info,
        ld_lines TYPE i,
        ld_linesc(10) TYPE c,
        lv_butxt TYPE butxt.

  SELECT SINGLE butxt INTO lv_butxt FROM t001
    WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs.
* Title
  wa_header-typ  = 'H'.
  wa_header-info = 'Collectors'' Action Report'.
  APPEND wa_header TO t_header.
  CLEAR wa_header.
* Date
  wa_header-typ  = 'S'.
  wa_header-key = 'Date: '.
  CONCATENATE  sy-datum+6(2) '.'
               sy-datum+4(2) '.'
               sy-datum(4) INTO wa_header-info.   "todays date
  APPEND wa_header TO t_header.
  CLEAR: wa_header.
* Bukrs
  wa_header-typ  = 'S'.
  wa_header-key = 'Company: '.
  CONCATENATE p_bukrs lv_butxt INTO wa_header-info SEPARATED BY space.
  APPEND wa_header TO t_header.
  CLEAR wa_header.

  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_COMMENTARY_WRITE'
    EXPORTING
      it_list_commentary = t_header.
ENDFORM.                    "top-of-page



*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  BUILD_FIELDCATALOG_AGREGGATE
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*  -->  p1        text
*  <--  p2        text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM build_fieldcatalog_agreggate .

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'KUNNR'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'Customer ID'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 0.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'NAME1'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'Customer Name'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 1.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION01'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'January'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 2.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION02'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'February'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 3.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION03'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'March'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 4.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION04'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'April'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 5.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION05'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'May'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 6.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION06'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'June'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 7.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION07'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'July'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 8.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION08'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'August'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 9.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION09'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'September'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 10.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION10'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'Octomber'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 11.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION11'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'Noveber'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 10.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.

  fieldcatalog-fieldname   = 'ACTION12'.
  fieldcatalog-seltext_m   = 'December'.
  fieldcatalog-col_pos     = 11.
  APPEND fieldcatalog TO fieldcatalog.
  CLEAR  fieldcatalog.


ENDFORM.                    " BUILD_FIELDCATALOG_AGREGGATE
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what you want to achieve - your question is very unclear, and your code example does not show any attempt to do anything besides assigning some values...

Comment: Please add a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially including the table declarations. The "correct" answer heavily depends on the table type of the target table (hashed would give the best runtime behavior, but might not be practical).

Comment: See again the question with the program at the end.

Comment: I don't have the time to sift through > 300 lines of mostly irrelevant code to identify the relevant parts, hence the M in MVCE

Comment: Maybe the analysis of my problem is not understandable. I wrote that I want to loop in an itab (it_collectoraction) fill the remaning fields and fill the 2nd itab(it_totalcollectoraction). The code from start-of-selection until the 1st perform (which do all the selection) is 60 lines and if you take out the case which is very simple (fill the fields of the 2nd itab according to the month) and is 40 lines, the remaining is almost 20 lines.                          Anyway thanks for you valuable time.

Answer (score 4):

If itab is not too big, then you can do like below.

```
    clear: itab2[].
    Loop at itab into wa_itab.
      wa_itab2-field1 = wa_itab-field1.
      wa_itab2-field2 = wa_itab-field2.
      wa_itab2-field3 = wa_itab-field3.
      wa_itab2-field4 = wa_itab-field4.
      ...
      read table itab2 into data(ls_itab2) with key field1 = wa_itab2-field1
                                                    field2 = wa_itab2-field2
                                                    field3 = wa_itab2-field3
                                                    ... 
                                                    binary search.
      if sy-subrc = 0 .
        " modify the line
         modify itab2 from wa_itab2 index sy-tabix.
      else.
        " append the line 
         append wa_itab2 to itab2.
         sort itab2 ascending by field1 field2 field3 ... . "the key fields.
      endif. 
    EndLoop.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_itab2> TYPE wa_itab2.
SORT itab2 BY bukrs kunnr.
LOOP AT itab INTO wa_itab.
***CHECK IF DATES EXIST***
READ TABLE itab2 ASSIGNING <fs_itab2> WITH KEY bukrs = wa_itab-bukrs
                                               kunnr = wa_itab-kunnr
                                               BINARY SEARCH.
 if sy-subrc = 0 . "if the record are founded
    <fs_itab2>-field1 = wa_itab-field1.
    <fs_itab2>-field2 = wa_itab-field2.
    <fs_itab2>-field3 = wa_itab-field3.
    ...
 else.  
  APPEND INITIAL LINE TO itab2 ASSIGNING <fs_itab2>.
  IF <fs_itab2> IS ASSIGNED.
    <fs_itab2>-field1 = wa_itab-field1.
    <fs_itab2>-field2 = wa_itab-field2.
    <fs_itab2>-field3 = wa_itab-field3.
    ...
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Thats is all with field symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need looping here, [`MOVE-CORRESPONDING`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abapmove-corresponding_itab.htm) do this for internal tables like a charm:

```
MOVE-CORRESPONDING src_tab TO target.
```

Here is the sample where `MWST` price conditions are selected into two itabs, then the currently valid ones are made invalid, then couple of additional invalid conditions with new key are added, and finally the second itab `lt_upd_konh` is updated, so that all MWST conditions in it gets invalidated with adding extra ones.

```
SELECT * FROM konh INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_konh) WHERE kschl = 'MWST'.
DATA(lt_upd_konh) = lt_konh.

LOOP AT lt_konh ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_konh>) WHERE datbi > sy-datum.
 <fs_konh>-datbi = sy-datum - 1.
ENDLOOP.

<fs_konh>-knumh = 1000.
APPEND <fs_konh> TO lt_konh.
<fs_konh>-knumh = 1001.
APPEND <fs_konh> TO lt_konh.
<fs_konh>-knumh = 1002.
APPEND <fs_konh> TO lt_konh.

MOVE-CORRESPONDING lt_konh TO lt_upd_konh.
```